# How do I get the website subdomain url that calls my API?

Tags: api, http, url, subdomain

I have A.Mysite.com and B.Mysite.com all calling my API.
Is there a way for my API to know where the request came from? (A.Mysite.com vs B.Mysite.com)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the two sites calling the API, you can configure the two to send an additional parameter to identify themselves, and use this to track them. You would need to modify the API to accept this additional parameter. This is the ideal solution.

Additionally, there are numerous http parameters that may be used to track the origin of a http request. If the two callers use two different static ip addresses, this would probably be the most reliable method. For example, if the API is written in PHP you could access the remote IP address using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

The domain/subdomain of a website is only used during DNS resolution, when you try to send to the domain. Each domain will always send as it's ip address. If they both originate from the same ip address, they will be indistinguishable unless you add an identifying parameter.